# react-table columns below instead of next to each other

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Iam trying to build a table with react-table. Everything works except that the columns are not shown next to each other, but below as you can see on the image.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import ReactTable from 'react-table'

class SnapshotsTable extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      snapshots: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch("http://myserver/snapshots")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => { 
        this.setState( {snapshots: data})
      })
  }

  render() {
    const columns = [
      { Header: 'ID',
        accessor: 'id'},
      { Header: 'Description',
        accessor: 'description'}
    ]
    return (
        <ReactTable data={this.state.snapshots} columns={columns} />
    )
  }

}

export default SnapshotsTable
```

[image: react-table]

unfortunately the image doesnt work, so here is the link: https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/8/22/33dbd31d987e2db3f14d0ac37c040cb7-full.png

Comment: Are you importing the stylesheet anywhere? The docs recommend something like `import 'react-table/react-table.css'` somewhere. Of course this means you need a CSS loader in your bundling setup

Comment: oh boys, that worked. thanks for the fast answer! had to add "import 'react-table/react-table.css'"

Comment: Also, I really like semantic-ui-react's tables and options (and their other react components, for that matter), you should take a look! https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/table/